# How do I split file content to write into another file?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, nltk

I receive a type error every time I try to split the contents of one file and write them into another.

The error suggests a string should be used instead of a list, so I've tried to convert it first but I still receive the same error. The file is a html page with the html tags removed, so that it is just plaintext

This is the error received

```
...............line 30, in split
w.write(re.split('[^\.\!\?]*[\.\!\?]',str(str1)))
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list
```

This is the python function

```
def split():
x=open("file_a.txt")
w= open("file_b.txt","w+")
str1= x.readlines()
w.write(re.split('[^\.\!\?]*[\.\!\?]',str(str1)))
```

Comment: The output of `split` is a list. You then try to `write` the list, but what does it mean to "write a list"? Would it be `[1, 2, 3]`, like Python would write it? Or `1<newline>2<newline>3<newline>`, one item per line? Maybe just stick the elements together, like `123`? English it up with `1, 2 and 3`? Specifically, what do you want when you say "split the contents of one file and write them into another"?

Answer (score 0):

str1 = x.readlines()

here str1 would be a list of lines from the file that you read. Instead you want to run the split operation on each line that you read from the file.

also by running the below line, you are trying to write a list to the output file. as the re.split operation returns a list.

w.write(re.split('[^.!\?]*[.!\?]',str(str1)))